# Recursively copy directories and files into destination

Tags: java, file, recursion, directory

We have the following task in Java:

> Given a list of directories and files followed by the destination copy all these directories(recursively) and files into the destination. Note: all the subdirectories and files inside the given directories must be kept in the same nested structure in destination folder.
>
> We take array of files as an input as well as the destination folder. The output must produce something like this:
>
> ```
> Started: resources\docs\books...
> Started: resources\docs\books\american...
> Started: resources\docs\books\american\London...
> Started: resources\docs\books\american\London\BEFORE ADAM.txt...
> Finished FILE: resources\docs\books\american\London\BEFORE ADAM.txt
> Total 229KB were copied!
> Started: resources\docs\books\american\London\THE IRON HEEL.txt...
> Finished FILE: resources\docs\books\american\London\THE IRON HEEL.txt
> Total 528KB were copied!
> Started: resources\docs\books\american\London\The People of the Abyss.txt...
> Finished FILE: resources\docs\books\american\London\The People of the Abyss.txt
> Total 370KB were copied!
> Finished FOLDER: resources\docs\books\american\London
> Finished FOLDER: resources\docs\books\american
> ```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Copy directories first creating an empty tree, copy files next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily achieve this by implementing the FileVisitor interface. This is a code sample just to show you how it works. It should do what you asked.

EDIT: Updated with custom size handling

```
public class FileCopier implements FileVisitor<Path> {

    private final Path sourcePath;
    private final Path targetPath;

    private HashMap<String, Long> mapSize;

    public FileCopier(Path sourcePath, Path targetPath) throws IOException {
        //Check whether the destination directory exists or not
        if (!Files.exists(targetPath)) {
            Files.createDirectories(targetPath);
        }

        this.sourcePath = sourcePath.toRealPath();
        this.targetPath = targetPath.toRealPath();
        this.mapSize = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        //Copying the directory first and then its content (directory copy does not copy its content)

        //Retrieving the last bit of the path starting from the source location
        Path lastBitPath = sourcePath.relativize(dir.toAbsolutePath().normalize());

        //Adding the last bit to the target path
        Path targetCopyPath = targetPath.resolve(lastBitPath).toAbsolutePath().normalize();

        if (!Files.exists(targetCopyPath)) {
            Files.copy(dir, targetCopyPath, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
        }

        //Defining 0 bytes for the new visited directory
        mapSize.put(targetCopyPath.toString(), 0L);
        System.out.println("Started: " + targetCopyPath);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        Path targetCopyPath = targetPath.resolve(sourcePath.relativize(file.toAbsolutePath().normalize())).toAbsolutePath().normalize();
        Files.copy(file, targetCopyPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
        
        //Adding the current copied file's bytes to the corresponding folder
        mapSize.put(targetCopyPath.getParent().toString(), mapSize.get(targetCopyPath.getParent().toString()) + Files.size(file));
        System.out.println("Finished FILE: " + targetCopyPath);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) {
        return FileVisitResult.TERMINATE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
        //Retrieving the last bit of the path starting from the source location
        Path lastBitPath = sourcePath.relativize(dir.toAbsolutePath().normalize());

        //Adding the last bit to the target path
        Path targetCopyPath = targetPath.resolve(lastBitPath).toAbsolutePath().normalize();

        //Showing the number of bytes copied within the copied directory
        System.out.println("Total " + this.mapSize.get(targetCopyPath.toString()) + " bytes were copied into " + targetCopyPath);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path sourcePath = Paths.get("./test");
        Path targetPath = Paths.get("./subtest");
        FileCopier fc = new FileCopier(sourcePath, targetPath);
        Files.walkFileTree(sourcePath, fc);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Files.size(dir)` doesn't do what you think it does - it isn't reporting the size of the files in the dir, nor the number of contents inside the directory.

Comment: @DuncG true let me clarify that I've written it like this only for simplicity and as a placeholder. She/he should keep track of every file size once copied and reset the value at every pre folder visit